# Font awesome icon is moving outside of its parent container with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position

I have a font awesome icon in a wrapper div.  The wrapper div has a positioning of absolute.  The font awesome icon also has a position of absolute.  The wrapper div needs to have absolute positioning because I am going to put it on the bottom edge of my header tag (not included in the code provided).

When I take away "position: absolute" from the font awesome icon, the icon no longer fits in the parent container.  I'm confused on why this is happening.  The parent to the icon is '.wrapper'  Therefore, by absolutely positioning the font awesome icon, I should be able to move it exactly where I want it to go inside '.wrapper', but instead it is moving outside of the wrapper class's border.

Here is when the icon has position: absolute:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Learn more</p>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header .wrapper {
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 400%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

header .wrapper i {
    position: absolute;
}

header .wrapper p {
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 30%;
}
```

[codepen] https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZXMzg?editors=1100

Here is when the icon does not have position: absolute:

```
header .wrapper {
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 400%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

header .wrapper i {
}

header .wrapper p {
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 30%;
}
```

[codepen] https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zezwKM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

> **The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.** It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

That is to say, when your icon is `position: absolute`, the parent container sizes itself as if the icon was not there (strictly, the icon takes up no space). So while you can indeed position it using `position: absolute` you'll just need to manually add spacing (e.g. using padding on the parent) to add enough space for it.

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdwmZz?editors=1100

Depending on your needs here it may be easier to just `position: static` to FontAwesome element (I also put the `i` element inside the `p` to avoid line break issues). https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Odgmvm?editors=1100

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your explanation.  I thought that "position:absolute" meant that the child element was guaranteed to be inside the parent element no matter what.  Thank you for correcting this large misunderstanding on my part.